# Lua regex to match pattern in makefile

Tags: makefile, lua, pattern-matching, lua-patterns

I'm writing a script to automate the mantainment of my makefile. I need a Lua pattern that matches the following lines:

```
# objects {
objects = build/somefile1.o \
          build/somefile2.o \
          ...
          build/somefileN.o \

# } objects
```

I tried with `%# objects %{[a-z%.%s%/%\\]+%# %} objects` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `# objects {.-\n# } objects`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I  suggest using:

```
"\n(# objects %b{} objects)"
```

*To make it work for cases when the match is at the start of the string, you need to prepend the string input with a newline*. Here, a newline is matched first, then`# objects`, then a space, then  `%b{}` matches balanced nested curly braces (if any) and then `objects` is matched.

When running the extraction, the captured part (within `(...)`) will be returned with `string.gmatch`.

See the [Lua online demo](https://ideone.com/KLbfc5)

```
s = [[ YOUR_TEXT_HERE ]]
for m in string.gmatch("\n" .. s, "\n(# objects %b{} objects)") do
   print(m)
 end
```